# Domain management (multiple servers)

Tags: dns, subdomain

Here's my scenario:

I have two web applications that are hosted on seperate servers.  What I'd like to do is have requests for "*.mydomain.com" (i.e. no subdomain, 'www', etc) to go to the first server, and requests for "mysubdomain.mydomain.com" to go to the second server.  How do I accomplish this?

Is it just a "CNAME" setting with my domain registrar?  like "www.mydomain.com" to ip 11.11.111.111?

I know this isn't necessarily programming related; however, I figured the asnwer would be helpful to others on the site as well, since most questions are web development related.

Thanks!

Comment: *sigh*... I'd be interested in waffle recipes, even though they aren't programming related. But there are other sites for that. This one is for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks shog! That's a perfect analogy, since this question is about as far off topic as asking for cooking recipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CNAME mysubdomain second.server
CNAME *  first.server
```

Answer (score 0):

CNAME is correct as stated in previous reply. You can add the A record too.

You will need to specify the server IP address where you would like to point *.mydomain.com and one more A record for mysubdomain.mydomain.com pointing to other server.

Make sure to add those DNS records from the server where mydomain.com is pointing and working.

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear to me if you just need a DNS resolution for your root domain mydomain.com or if you need a wildcard subdomain (*) which will means any subdomain.

If you know the the first and second server by their name, ie. first-server.com and second-server.com, then you will use CNAME Records, in the zone of mydomain.com add or change:

```
*.mydomain.com. IN CNAME first-server.com.
mysubdomain.mydomain.com. IN CNAME second-server.com.
```

If you have the IPs instead of the names, and you are in control of those IPs, I mean that those IPs will not change without your knowledge, then use A records, in the zone of mydomain.com add or change:

```
*.mydomain.com. IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
mysubdomain.mydomain.com. IN A YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
```

where XXX is the IP of the first server and YYY the ip of the second server.

NOTES:

If you have currently an A record, you will have to remove it in order to set the CNAME, you cant have both.

If you don't want a wildcard subdomain but a root domain resolution, then a CNAME will not work, that is because will conflict with SOA records, in that case an A record is a must.